# How to solve a system of a single equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I’m trying to solve an apparently simple problem but couldn’t find a solution not involving advanced math.

Let $10ax + (b-3a) = x - 3$

How do we solve equations of the given form? The solution of the above quation is $10a=1$ and $b-3a=-3$, so they basically turned a single equation into two different equations, but there is no explanation of how and I couldn’t  find a explanation online.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: [equating coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equating_coefficients)

Comment: First see the comment of J.W.Tanner and the answer of Anonymath.  The foundation of the analysis is that if $(c)x + d = (e)x + f,~$ then $~c=e~$ and $~d=f.$

Comment: Ok I got it, by equating coefficients you mean 10ax = x and b-3a = -3? That’s pretty simple to be honest I feel pretty dumb about it now

Answer (score 1):

The equation implies that the equality holds for any real $x$. Setting two different values of $x$ (such as $0$ and $1$) will give you two different equations with the above solutions. I those two equalities hold, then $ 10ax + (b-3a) = x - 3$ for all real $x$.

Comment: Thanks Anonymath, I think I understand what they did, first turning x = 0 we obtain b-3a=-3 , then by inputting x=1 and b-3a=-3 into 10ax+(b-3a) = x-3 we get 10a=1, I don’t really get the logic behind it but I will look up about equating coefficients and about the other comment, I think I’m starting to grasp it, thank you very much!